# Installing Boost numeric bindings

Tags: c++, boost, numeric

Is the latest version of Boost numeric bindings in here:
http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings/ ?

Are these only header files? So I don't need to compile and "install" it as such, just include from my programmes?

Also, where can I find examples or tutorial of how these should be used?

Comment: Guess this link can help "Numeric Library Bindings for Boost UBlas"- http://mathema.tician.de/software/boost-bindings

Comment: @SChepurin, the link you provided seems quite out of date, the last version in from 2008.

Comment: My condolences. I said "i guess" it can help and it sure can. There is no general installation tutorial in boost. You have to consult with designated page depending on the platform. Like here "Header-Only Libraries" -http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries for "Unix Variants" (boost's terminology).

Answer (score 2):

> Is the latest version of Boost numeric bindings in here: http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings/ ?

I hope so, at least it was the latest version before boost switched from svn to git. David Bellot should know, he can be reached via http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/ublas.

> Are these only header files? So I don't need to compile and "install" it as such, just include from my programmes?

Yes and no. The bindings are only header files, but you still need to link your program against lapack (or blas, atlas, umfpack, mumps).

> Also, where can I find examples or tutorial of how these should be used?

Some documentation can be found at http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings/libs/numeric/bindings/doc/html/index.html

Some examples can be found at http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/numeric_bindings/libs/numeric/bindings/lapack/test/

In general, the people at http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/ublas seem to be helpful, if you try to use the bindings (or ublas) and run into problems. But I'm not sure if any of them checks here at stackoverflow for potential users that ran into problems.